# Issue with discord bot: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound

Tags: python, discord, bots

So my friend challenged me to make an 8ball bot for discord, and I tried

I searched the internet for answers, and I couldn't find one, no where.

I tried redefining everything, I just don't know what the issue is.

Not to mention, when I tried to set the bot status, that didn't work either

````
 @bot.command(name='8ball', help='Gives the answer to any of your questions')
 async def quotelist(ctx):
     quotelist = [
         'As I see it, yes.',
         'Ask again later.',
         'Better not tell you now.',
         'Cannot predict now.',
         'Concentrate and ask again.',
         'Don\'t count on it.',
         'It is certain.',
         'It is decided so.',
     ]
 
     response = random.choices(quotelist)
     await ctx.send(response)
 
 bot.run("token here")```
````

Comment: Just to be clear, you're getting the error when you type `!8ball` in chat?

Comment: Unable to replicate issue. What version of discord.py are you using? (`pip show discord.py`)

Comment: @Allister It's an issue with the !8ball command at the moment, and the discord.py version is  1.5.1